# Max Upload Size Handle in AJAX request Validation Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, bootstrap-modal

How do I handle the the set Max Upload Size in my ajax request to alert the user the file is to big. This is for multiple files which can be accepted. I have an alert ready on the HTML side with an ID called "MaximumFileUpload" I just dont know how to call it, i assume using an IF statement. Can someone advise?

Ajax request to server side:

```
function makeProgress(number){   
          var url = getRelativeURL("web/fileUpload");   
          var formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('number', number);
          fls = document.getElementById("attachmentFileUploadInput").files; //number of files... 
          console.log(fls);
          for(j=0;j<fls.length;j++){
              formData.append('files[]', fls[j]);  //note files[] not files
              $.ajax({
                  url : url,
                  data : formData,
                  processData : false,
```

Config file:

`commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(5000000); // 5000000 -> 5MB`

Comment: Simply check the file size of each file in your server script. If one of them exceeds the max file size, send back an error in your AJAX response.

Comment: Can you advise how to do this check of each file size in the array? How do i reference the commonsMultipartResolver max upload size?